# My user has granted all permissions for authentication scopes to google calendar, but the API is returning a 403 error?

Tags: google-calendar-api

My user has granted all permissions for authentication scopes to google calendar, but the API is returning a 403 error. However, this only happens for some users. Most user do not have any problem.

I reviewed this live with the user as they granted access and can confirm that they did grant access to all the scopes but the issue still persists.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] and include the full error message as there are a number of 403 errors

Comment: I've added in a photo of the error message. I'd be happy to share some code as well, but this is a very one off error. My code has been working for all my users except this one. I'm wondering if there is something I don't know about authentication when it comes to specific users

Comment: In the future remember that you need to post your code and the error message not images.  without seeing your code its hard to help you need to show us your code.

Comment: Is this a domain app? Is the user perhaps logged into more than one account (there are bugs associated with being logged in to more than one account)? Can they try doing the whole process in incognito mode?

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing an api endpoint that requests privet user data you must be authorized to access that data.  You haven't posted your code or stated which method you are trying to use but as an example lets look at

[Events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) in order to use this method the documentation tells us that you need to authorize the user with one of the following scopes

[image]

If you authorize your application with a difference scope and not one of these you will get the error message you are seeing Insufficient authentication scopes.

The key to fixing this will be to fix your code to ensure that you are sending the proper scopes, then to revoke the users access and force the system to prompt the user for consent again.  The user must see the consent screen again showing the new scope required. Once the user has authorized with the new scope it will work.

It is probably running on an old access token and refresh token without prompting the user for authorize again.

The insufficient scopes means that the user has authorized your application bu